# StudentSubmissions.Patch UpdateMask Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-classroom

Trying to use the StudentSubmissions.Patch part of the Classroom API in Google Apps Script and keeping running across this error

> updateMask: updateMask may only contain "draftGrade" or
>   "assignedGrade"

Here is my code for that particular section:

```
var studentSubmission = {'draft_grade':'88'}
var patchC = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.patch(studentSubmission, courseId, cwId, submissionId);
```

There is clearly something wrong with the way I am passing the StudentSubmission Resource parameter, but I can't figure out why...

This is clearly the documentation I am referring to - https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch

**UPDATE**

I was able to change the code a bit to reflect what you both were saying. Obviously, I didn't use exactly what you both said because KENdi's example is in Python and Ein2012, it would error out on the *var patchC = Classroom...* line.

I changed some things that now look like this:

```
var studentSubmission = {'draftGrade':'88'}
   var extra =  {'updateMask':'draftGrade'};
   var patchC = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.patch(studentSubmission, courseId, cwId, submissionId, extra);
```

But now I get a different error "@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request". So, now I'm unsure if that formatting is correct and there is some Developer Console situation I haven't resolved (although feel as though I'm correct), or that new formatting is wrong and I'm just getting the wild permission error.

I saw this [Similar Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313748/google-classroom-api-modifyattachments) but what if the course work was one created normally through classroom and not via a script? Ahh.

Comment: I have created a request for change of authentication; we'll see what happens of it. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67748271

Answer (score 1):

specify update mask fields and later execute and also specify names as instructed in the documentation ("draftGrade","assignedGrade")

```
var studentSubmission = {'draftGrade':'88'}
var patchC = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.patch(studentSubmission, courseId, cwId, submissionId);
patchC.UpdateMask = "draftGrade";


var response = submisionObj.Execute();
```

Comment: I was able to change the code a bit to reflect what you both were saying. Obviously, I didn't use exactly what you both said because KENdi's example is in Python and Ein2012, it would error out on the var patchC = Classroom... line.

I changed some things that now look like this:
'code'

Answer (score 0):

From your error, it is stated that the `updateMask` must only contain "`draftGrade`" or "`assignedGrade`". So from your code, you need only that two value for the updateMask.

The [`updateMask`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch#query-parameters) identifies which fields on the student submission to update. This field is required to do an update. The update fails if invalid fields are specified

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework#grade_student_responses), The [`StudentSubmission`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions) resource has two fields to store grades: `assignedGrade`, which is the grade reported to students, and `draftGrade`, which is a tentative grade visible only to teachers. These fields are updated using `courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.patch` with a field mask containing the appropriate fields.

Here is the example code on how to do that.

```
studentSubmission = { 
'assignedGrade': 99, 
'draftGrade': 80 
} 
service.courses().courseWork().studentSubmission().patch( 
courseId=<course ID or alias>, 
courseWorkId=<courseWork ID>, 
id=<studentSubmission ID>, 
updateMask='assignedGrade,draftGrade', 
body=studentSubmission).execute()
```