# How to update student grades via classroom API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-classroom

I'm trying to integrate Google classroom API into a ASP.net(c#) web application.
I want to update student grades via Classroom submission API. While updating its throwing the exception **"updateMask may only contain "draftGrade" or "assignedGrade". [400]"**

The code i have used is

```
  var studentSubmision = new Google.Apis.Classroom.v1.Data.StudentSubmission()
            {
                AssignedGrade = double.Parse(param["assignedGrade"]),
                DraftGrade = double.Parse(param["draftGrade"])
            };

            var response= service.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.Patch(studentSubmision, param["courseId"],
                    param["courseWorkId"], param["submissionId"]).Execute();
```

I have gone through the API doc link [Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework) .How can i specify the updatemask fields.

Comment: I think you already answer this problem, according to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484693/studentsubmissions-patch-updatemask-error) that you already answered

Comment: After some trying I have solved the problem .... http://stackoverflow.com/a/38504149/2535851