# Unable to grade student work via API if assignment was created in the Google Classroom UI

Tags: google-classroom

Steps to reproduce:

- Create an assignment in a course in the Google Classroom UI as an instructor
- As the instructor, get an oauth2 token
- Call into the Google Classroom API as the instructor (PATCH /v1/courses/:courseId/courseWork/:assignmentId/studentSubmissions/submissionId)

This triggers a 403 permissions error: @ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.

However, if I repeat the same steps using an assignment created via the API instead of the UI, everything works fine. I'm curious if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You got [ProjectPermissionDenied](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Access.Errors#projectpermissiondenied) because some request in the Google Classroom API must only be made by the Developer Console project of the [OAuth client ID](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849), that is used to create the corresponding course work item.

Here is [one example](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch) of that.

For creating assignment, I think this link will help you with that.

For more information, just read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started) of Google Classroom API and check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313748/google-classroom-api-modifyattachments).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you specifically address whether you would expect what I am trying to do (create an assignment in the UI, grade it via the API) to work, or not? As far as I can tell, the same user is both making the assignment in the UI and grading it with the API (I only have one user).