# Get the student´s submission id of a google classroom assignment

Tags: google-classroom

I want to return assignments in Google Classrom using

service().courseWork().studentSubmissions().return_(courseId=PASS_HERE_THE_COURSEID, courseWorkId=PASS_HERE_THE_COURSEWORDID, id=PASS_HERE_THE_SUBMISSION_ID)

I have the courseId and the courseWorkId, but don´t know how to get the id=PASS_HERE_THE_SUBMISSION_ID for each student.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list) to get a list of [student submissions](http://StudentSubmission). You just need to provide the `courseId` and `courseWorkId` as a [path parameter](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list#path-parameters). You may also include additional [query parameters](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list#query-parameters) in your request.

For example, you want to restrict returned student work to those owned by the student with the specified identifier. You need to set a specific identifier to `userId` as part of your [query parameters](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list#query-parameters)

> Note: You may also loop all the list of student submission to process each submission before returing it using [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.return](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/return)

- The numeric identifier for the user
- The email address of the user
- The string literal "me", indicating the requesting user

**Sample Response Body (JSON):**

```
{
  "studentSubmissions": [
    {
      object (StudentSubmission)
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string
}
```

[StudentSubmission](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions#resource:-studentsubmission) contains all the information related to the student submission for the course work including the `courseId`, `courseWorkId`, `id` and `userId`.

**StudentSubmission Resource (JSON):**

```
{
  "courseId": string,
  "courseWorkId": string,
  "id": string,
  "userId": string,
  "creationTime": string,
  "updateTime": string,
  "state": enum (SubmissionState),
  "late": boolean,
  "draftGrade": number,
  "assignedGrade": number,
  "alternateLink": string,
  "courseWorkType": enum (CourseWorkType),
  "associatedWithDeveloper": boolean,
  "submissionHistory": [
    {
      object (SubmissionHistory)
    }
  ],

  // Union field content can be only one of the following:
  "assignmentSubmission": {
    object (AssignmentSubmission)
  },
  "shortAnswerSubmission": {
    object (ShortAnswerSubmission)
  },
  "multipleChoiceSubmission": {
    object (MultipleChoiceSubmission)
  }
  // End of list of possible types for union field content.
}
```

---

### (UPDATE)

Regarding the error you have encountered when using [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.return](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/return) in Apps Script,

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.return failed with error: @ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.

It occurred because you are trying to modify a course work which is not created on a Developer Console project. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38336897/14606046).

**Sample Code:**

```
  var courseId = '2491255xxxxxx';
  var courseWorkId = '2524434xxxxx'; // manually created in classroom.google.com
  
  //1st TRY with error
  var studentSubmissions = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(courseId, courseWorkId);
  Logger.log(studentSubmissions.studentSubmissions[0].id);
  //var ret = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.return({},courseId, courseWorkId, studentSubmissions.studentSubmissions[0].id);
  //Logger.log(ret);



  var assignment =  {
    title: "Test Assignment 3",
    state: "DRAFT",
    assigneeMode: "ALL_STUDENTS",
    workType: "ASSIGNMENT"
  };

  //var newCourseWork = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(assignment, courseId);
  //2nd TRY without error
  var newCourseWorkId = '2618921xxxxx';
  var studentSubmissions2 = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(courseId, newCourseWorkId);
  var ret = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.return({},courseId, newCourseWorkId, studentSubmissions2.studentSubmissions[0].id);
  Logger.log(studentSubmissions2);
  Logger.log(ret);
  
 Logger.log(Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.get(courseId,newCourseWorkId));
```

**Explanation:**

1. During the first try, I tried to return a student submission course work which was created in https://classroom.google.com/. This case will encounter an error, since I am trying to modify a course work that is not associated with a developer console project. You can check if a course work has an associated developer console project using `Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.get()`, `associatedWithDeveloper` property should be **true**.
2. On the 2nd try, I created a draft course work first, then modify the created course work in https://classroom.google.com/. Once I finalized the changes and published the course work. I tried to return the student submission course work and it was successful (return should be null/empty). The reason why it succeed is because a developer console project is associated with the course work since I created the course work using Apps Script, hence I could also modify the student submission using Apps Script.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Ron! I´ll try to follow your indications. 

Comment: Please let me know if you will encounter some issues. If ever this work feel free to accept or upvote the answer as reference to others. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Ron! 
I´ve used this line in my script to get one student submission id:
 Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(courseId, courseWorkId).studentSubmissions[0].id;  
as you suggested and I could get it.
But now I want to use this id for returning the assignment and there is a parameter that I don´t understand.
It says
return(ReturnStudentSubmissionRequest resource, String courseId, String courseWorkId, String id) 

I´ve got everything except ReturnStudentSubmissionRequest resource

Do you know what it means?

Comment: I'm not sure what programming language you are currently using, but if your library expects a `ReturnStudentSubmissionRequest resource` parameter this pertains to the request body. Based on the [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.return](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/return) request body should be empty, you can declare an empty `resource` variable something like this `resource = {}`

Comment: Hi @Ron
My script is very simple using Google Apps Script editor.

`function returnAssignment() {
    
    var resource = {};
  
 Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.return(resource, '77627855704', '150547015058', 'Cg4IpoHnnqMEEJLLtOqwBA');
 
   }`

and the error is this
GoogleJsonResponseException: La llamada de la API a classroom.courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.return falló con el error: @ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.

Comment: Hi i updated the answer based on the error that you encountered

Comment: Hi Ron! Now I see why I can´t return the assignment, as it was created in Google Classroom... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I´ve done so, but when I click on the up arrow, there´s a message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Thank you again for your help. I think the answer can help other users.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn´t see the ✔. I´ve done it.